# Appending .lp files in Gurobi

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, gurobi

I am trying to solve a MIP on Gurobi but the build time is extremely long. I have a loop that looks like this (I had an explicit loop but this built-in function is more optimized):

```
m.addConstrs((quicksum(X_rdc_to_dist[j,i,s,t] for j in rdc_list) == demand_fcst_df.loc[(demand_fcst_df['ADDR_BOOK_N'] == i)&
                                           (demand_fcst_df['SKU'] == s)&
                                           (demand_fcst_df['DATE'] == t),'CASES'].sum())
             for i in dist_list
             for s in sku_list
             for t in time_periods_list
             )
```

The length of each of those lists are as follows:

```
len(rdc_list) = 10
len(cdc_list) = 5
len(sku_list) = 20
len(dist_list) = 1333
len(time_period_list) = 100
```

This loop takes insanely long to build. Gurobi does not support multithreaded builds for the same model. However, it does allow building separate models on different threads. Is there a way to build separate `.lp` files(may be save it as .txt file) and then append them into one model and solve it?
I am trying to reduce the build time.

Are there any other open source packages that support multithreading? I can build a `.lp` file using that and then solve it using Gurobi.

Comment: It would be useful to profile how much time is spent in the first quicksum versus the second, which appears to be over a list created from a Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: Yup! I ended up analyzing the `quicksum` and `addConstrs`. They are pretty quick. It was the `.loc` list creations and summing them up that took longer. I replaced the `.loc` function by creating a dictionary from the DataFrame and indexing that dictionary. That solved the time issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.loc` function was slowing down the loop. I converted the `DataFrame` into a `dict` and saved it as a `pickle` (just a once). Then I read data from that `pickle` every time the model runs. If the data needs to be changed, I create a new `pickle`.